# Save data on pdf after updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf

I have application for managing orders . User can create order , and after creating it generate pdf with data from order . This pdf need to send to user via email.
Also, pdf need to be saved on admin panel in table so admin can download it .

The problem is how to save this pdf after creating order so any update price or other data does not affect on created pdf . PDF need to stay with all data which was in ordering time.

Application is on Ruby on Rails .

Thanks .

Comment: I am using prawn for generate pdfs . But can you explain me how is this possible ?

Comment: Ok, no probs . I need help or idea . Anything . Thanks

Comment: Is just 2 lines nothing else nothing out normal..and is more easy than prawn....sorry if i cant help now...need some rest...if u want answer this message in 7h

Comment: Great . Waiting for u .

Answer (score 0):

Use  wicked pdf gem.

```
1.You must install https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/
2.Install the gem with the command "gem install wkhtmltopdf-binary"
3.Create a folder to save your pdf files like "/public/user_pdfs"
4.Configure your controller

class UserController < ApplicationController
  def pdf_files
   @users= User.all
   respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf  { 
      send_data render(
        ####### WICKED CODE ######
        :pdf => "user_pdfs" },
        :save_to_file => Rails.root.join('public/user_pdfs', "name_of_pdf_on_Db.pdf")
        ),
        ####### END WICKED CODE ######
        :filename => "name_of_pdf_in_view.pdf"
    }       
   end     
  end
end

5.In the view "pdf_files.html.erb"just create a link to download the file

 <% @users.each do |user| %>
   <%= user.name %>
   <%= link_to "DOWNLOAD PDF",{:controller=>"user",:action=>"pdf_files",:id=>user.id } %>
 <% end %>

6.Create the pdf file just the information that you want to show ...."pdf_files.erb"

 <% @users.each do |user| %>
   <%= user.name %>
 <% end %>
```

For more information go to https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf

Comment: But I'am using prawn gem . It's used before I started and everything working fine but store to folder . Is there any option for prawn gem and storing to folder ??